# Thesis Theme -> hooks not working for custom function

Tags: hooks, theme-thesis

I added this small and innocent function to the master.php

```
add_action('hook_before_footer', 'categorydescription');

function categorydescription() {
    echo "<?php echo category_description(); ?>";
}
```

It does its job, but there is a problem.

It does not matter whichever standard or custom hook I choose, the content pulled onto the page by the function category_description() is always shown at the very bottom of the page, underneath the footer (you have to scroll down to the very bottom of the page to see the content)

https://www.vorfaelligkeitsentschaedigung.net/anwalt-kanzlei/c/bad-nauheim/

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you very much in advance,
Roman

Comment: it's probably because you're outputting raw PHP code, if you want to execute PHP code in your theme e.g. to display a category description, that is not how you do it. This isn't a WordPress problem but a beginner PHP problem, you can't run PHP code by putting it inside quotes and inserting it inside more PHP code like that

Comment: what would be your suggestion? how would you do it?